# Unable to open file DFM using cmake on c++ builder 10.3

Tags: c++, delphi, cmake, c++builder

I am getting the following linker error in my project.

`Error: Unable to open file 'FOO.DFM'`

I am compiling with the old borland compiler (not clang) and building using cmake rather than the IDE. I have added the directory of the dfm file to `target_include_directories`. Compilation is successful but having this issue with multiple `dfm` files at the linking stage.

In the .cbproj file of the ide this is used like the following way:

```
</CppCompile>
<FormResources Include="foo.dfm"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm wondering is this because the delphi compiling isn't occurring through cmake (`dcc32`). Is this supported or do you need to have a custom `add_custom_command` in your cmake to handle this. [C++ Builder](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_CMake_with_C%2B%2B_Builder) docs doesn't seem to mention any delphi compilation.

In the IDE build output one of the initial tasks is the delphi compilation, you can see `c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\dcc32.exe -B` but this is not happening in cmake output

Comment: are those `*.dfm` files in the same folder as used `*.cpp` and `*.h` files for the same forms? Which C++Builder?

Comment: @Spektre Yes they are in the same folder as the source and headers. C++ builder 10.3.

Comment: and the forms where `Added to Project` or just included and created dynamicaly?

Comment: @Spektre This was an original project always compiled from ide, now being updated to use cmake. So I'm not sure how originally they were added.

Comment: Ow I never used CMAKE ...

Comment: @Spektre Yes this is the main issue, cmake